# How to restrict distortion along curve?

Tags: curve-modifier

So, a curve modifier distorts meshes to fit a curve. What I don't get is that the curve modifier distorts the mesh where it is not needed. For instance, where the curve goes straight, I expect the mesh to be not distorted at all. As in the example below, I expect distortion around the corners, instead of everyone else. Is there any way to restrict distortion along a curve?

[image]

Comment: i know you might not want it, but you could give geometry nodes a try? or parent your objects?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sTHiRZebl48

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say it is caused by modifier stack where Arrayed object is taken into account for Curve modifier as single object - imagine that as object seen as inside a cage with deform control point at curve points ... alll between is interpolated. That is why it is squeezed on the way.

[image]

If you want to avoid such behaviour you would have to add more control points (for curve object) ...

[image]

I would take Chris's offer with GN :)

Comment: Adding control points works for me, geometry nodes are overkill here. The array modifier is not the problem.