# Is there a way to preserve the thickness of a (poly) curve?

Tags: bezier-curves

I have a poly curve which makes a square, so the thickness of the curve remains constant. When I move one of the handles downwards, elongating the shape, the thickness of the curve changes:

[image]

Is there a way to maintain the thickness of the curve automatically? I've found I can subdivide the sides and then move the resulting points very close to but not at the downmost vertex to achieve what I want, but that feels a bit weird.

Comment: No, there is not other way for this kind of object (adding control point closer to angle is the only "weird" way as you already noticed). Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/273773/2214

Comment: Womp. Oh well, thanks anyways

Answer (score 8):

Well, yes, **if** your curve is 2D, and is declared to be 2D, at the top of  its Data tab > Shape panel. Then Blender knows how to mitre the corners:

[image]

(For curve *Bevel* profiles .. not for *Curve* modifier deformations)

Comment: Right :) +1 ... my memory goes shorter and shorter https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/253501/2214

Comment: @vklidu maybe you're just not frustrated by the behaviour of 3D curves as often as me :) But, _is_  there a sensible and general  3D mitring solution, without further parameters? Not sure..

Answer (score 4):

By default a curve object is placed as [**3D curve**](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/curves/properties/shape.html). For this kind of curve, there is not better way ... only by adding more control points closer to angle keep lines thickness, but you will always deal with the issue at corners. Similar, but easier you result with curve converted to mesh object and using *Skin* modifier.

If your goal is **[2D shape](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/275475/2214)**, than Robin Betts's answer is your way :)

---

It is happening because Blender calculates same profile shape at each control point.
*(Here I converted a Curve to a Mesh just for visualisation purpose.)*

[image]

To keep curve "thickness" consistent - profile has to be changed according to curve's segments angle ...

[image]

... sadly, that is not happening in Blender for 3D type curve.

---

Under Curve Properties you can change *Mean Radius*, but since you can't specify X/Y radius separately - the fix in one direction destroys profile in second direction ... so, it is useless as well ...

[image]

---

For this specific shape it is just better to convert into a mesh, Inset Face, Delete and Extrude (or add Solidify modifier).