# How do slant on object?

Tags: modifiers, curve-modifier

Sorry , my English is poor so I will try to explain my problem so easy as I can.

1. I create and modify Plane.
   [image: Plane]
2. Expand it up.
   [image: Expanded plane]
3. And now I would like to get this 45deg slant.
   [image: Slant]
4. to expand verticles right to get frame corner.
   [image: Frame corner]

So far i have been doing it like this:

5. I create new plane and rotate it 45deg.
   [image: new plane]
6. Then every verticles move up to snap face of new plane.
   [image: snap to plane]

It works but it is tedious. It can be done manually for a dozen or so vertices, but not for several hundred. I try boolean modifier but I am not satisfied with the effect.
I'm sure there's an easier way to do this type of modification, what is it?

Comment: @Moonboots  answers you for the general case. But if it's a flat frame / cornice, the easiest way to  mitred joints  is to [profile a 2D Curve](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/275475/35559)

Answer (score 10):

You can use the *Boolean* tool but you can also:

Use the *Bisect* tool (same button as the *Knife* tool, just keep pressing on it to switch the *Bisect* tool), select your whole mesh and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to constrain to 45°:

[image]

Tweak the parameters in the *Operator* box in order to remove the top part and to fill the hole:

[image]

Or, even simpler, use the *Shear* tool: select the top of your mesh, press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> and <kbd>Y</kbd> to move the vertices on the view Y axis, <kbd>1</kbd> to tilt 45°, and <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Shear tool is what I need. Bisect is ok too, but there is hard to set specific angle (angle of 45 degrees just right easy). All tools will be useful for me. Thanks again.